# Why do Android SDL_SetVideoMode crash when not called by main thread?

Tags: android, sdl

I am facing a strange issue i can't solve.
I use SDL on android to display frames decoded by ffmpeg.
If the SDL renderer is directly created in the main fonction, and then initialized, there is no trouble

```
05-31 09:24:11.442: V/SDL(11376): pixel format RGB_565
05-31 09:24:11.442: I/SDL(11376): SDL_Android_Init()
05-31 09:24:11.442: I/Main(11376): Entering main
05-31 09:24:13.817: I/SDLRenderer(11376): Entering SDLRenderer::init
05-31 09:24:13.817: I/SDLRenderer(11376): SDLRenderer::init -> About to create screen with w=704 h=480
05-31 09:24:13.817: I/SDL(11376): [STUB] GL_LoadLibrary
05-31 09:24:13.822: V/SDL(11376): Starting up OpenGL ES 2.0
05-31 09:24:13.827: D/libEGL(11376): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
05-31 09:24:13.832: D/libEGL(11376): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
05-31 09:24:13.832: D/libEGL(11376): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
05-31 09:24:13.837: D/(11376): Device driver API match
05-31 09:24:13.837: D/(11376): Device driver API version: 10
05-31 09:24:13.837: D/(11376): User space API version: 10 
05-31 09:24:13.837: D/(11376): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Fri May  4 10:32:42 KST 2012 
05-31 09:24:13.862: I/SDL(11376): [STUB] GL_SetSwapInterval
05-31 09:24:13.862: I/SDL(11376): [STUB] GL_GetSwapInterval
05-31 09:24:13.932: I/SDLRenderer(11376): SDLRenderer::init -> screen created with w=704 h=480
05-31 09:24:13.932: I/SDLRenderer(11376): SDLRenderer::init -> About to create YUV Overlay with SDL_YV12_OVERLAY and w=704 h=480
05-31 09:24:13.932: I/SDLRenderer(11376): SDLRenderer::init -> YUV Overlay created with SDL_YV12_OVERLAY and w=704 h=480
```

BUT if in the main function, I create a thread that do the previous job (created renderer and initialize it) it crash..

```
05-31 10:33:04.462: V/SDL(23043): pixel format RGB_565
05-31 10:33:04.462: I/SDL(23043): SDL_Android_Init()
05-31 10:33:04.462: I/Main(23043): Entering main
05-31 10:33:05.882: I/Main(23043): Main: About to create thread DecodeVideo
05-31 10:33:05.882: I/Main(23043): Starting DecodeVideo
05-31 10:33:06.457: I/SDLRenderer(23043): Entering SDLRenderer::init
05-31 10:33:06.462: I/SDLRenderer(23043): SDLRenderer::init -> About to create screen with w=704 h=480
05-31 10:33:06.462: I/SDL(23043): [STUB] GL_LoadLibrary
05-31 10:33:06.462: A/libc(23043): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000364 (code=1)
```

does anybody knows if there is something special to do to solve that ?
Thank you.
Zbb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from [documentation](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.fcg/SDL_SetVideoMode).

*Note 3: This function should be called in the main thread of your application. *

Comment: There cannot be better answer...I am confused. I am sure I read the document a thousand times but never paid attention to the notes..Many thanks for pointing me out this "detail..."

Comment: At least for 1.2.x this is the case (some docu might not mention it?) sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_SetVideoMode does. Anyway for me it was a hang, not a crash. SDL_WM_SetCaption also caused a hang from a separate thread.  I did discover through trial and error that on windows, you can call this in any thread as long as that thread was the one to call SDL_Init initially, so...FWIW.